Unsupport Operation System uploading image to Firebase on Flutter web
I had read documentations (here and others sites), but I can not still load an image from FIREBASE. I can insert data, update it and so, but no image.
The project is in Flutter WEB and I am testing it using the variable KIsWeb. Here's the code snippet:
imageName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('productImages/$imageName.jpg');
var uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(_image!);
downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();

I am using flutter 3.22.3 and Dart 3.4.4
